# Facebook iOS sdk to take user id

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

a question about Facebook sdk for iOS.

If I have an active session how can I get only the user ID?

Is there a simple way to obtain this id without use this example code?

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *aUser, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 // I can take the user id..
             }
         }];
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
+ (NSString *)activeUserId {
    return [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID;
}
```

if you are already logged in on facebook.

Comment: Actually quite simple ;-).

Comment: Here is documentation on it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/

Answer (score 8):

This is best way to take user id, instead of directly access using dot.

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *aUser, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"User id %@",[aUser objectForKey:@"id"]);
             }
         }];
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the id of the user without having to run an new request in facebook (in particular, so I would not use an asynchronous request)

Comment: @Safari I used to use this method. It consumes very little time. It's not a bottle neck.

Comment: It's a huge issue for me because it runs asynchronously… Now I have to wait for it to finish somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          NSDictionary *result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          _fbId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                      }];
```